# is there a possibility to disable inheritance while screen width is less than X?

Tags: html, css

I am making simple website with my friend and he did 'sticky' header which decreases for example font-size while scrolling but we do not want these classes to "work" when website is in mobile version. Is there a possibility to turn that inheritance off when our website width is less than 400px for example? I mean we have media queries but we do not want this code to start working when website is in media screen max width 400px mode is it even possible? thanks a lot for all responses.

```css
/* I want this to work when screen is bigger than 1024px */

header.sticky a {
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  transition: .5s;
  font-weight: 500;
}
header.sticky
{
   background-color: RGB(105,0,0,0.8);
   transition: .5s;
}
header a.active
{
   color: #E6AF2E;
}

header.sticky .logo{
   margin: 0;
   transition: .5s;
   font-size: 40px;
}

/* that was standard header */
header{
  font-weight: 500;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s;
}

header h1{
   font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 48px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   transition: 0.3s;
    transition: .5s;
}

header h1:hover{
  color: #E6AF2E;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Why don't media queries work...isn't this the point of them?

Comment: Hi, I have styles in media queries but they don't work and this header sticky is "executing".

Comment: please can you show the sticky header javascript as it seems that is what you want to amend

Answer (score 0):

You can use, instead of `max-width: 400px;`, `min-width: 1024px;` for the media query.

Comment: I do not know why I am so stupid.. it works of course thanks man and sorry guys for stupid question I am very begginer so don't be angry. Have a nice day:)

Comment: No one is going to be angry. Making mistakes like this are also welcome here. We're all human after all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to wrap the first part in a media query?

eg:

```css
/* I want this to work when screen is bigger than 1024px */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  header.sticky a {
      padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 100;
      transition: .5s;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    header.sticky
    {
       background-color: RGB(105,0,0,0.8);
       transition: .5s;
    }
    header a.active
    {
       color: #E6AF2E;
    }

    header.sticky .logo{
       margin: 0;
       transition: .5s;
       font-size: 40px;
    }
}

/* that was standard header */
header{
  font-weight: 500;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s;
}

header h1{
   font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 48px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   transition: 0.3s;
    transition: .5s;
}

header h1:hover{
  color: #E6AF2E;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Yes man that was the point thanks and sorry for stupid question.

Comment: No problem @nvrgonnagiveuup, don’t worry that is what stack overflow is for!

Comment: don’t forget you can also use `min-width` and `max-width` in a single media query, eg:
`@media only screen and (min-device-width: 400px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)`